# What is "deps" in "implementation deps.support.app_compat"?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I was looking in to the google sample for the new architecture component, where I found the the code as below:

```
dependencies {
    // Support libraries
    implementation deps.support.app_compat
    implementation deps.support.v4
    implementation deps.support.design
    implementation deps.support.cardview

    // Architecture components
    implementation deps.lifecycle.runtime
    implementation deps.lifecycle.extensions
    annotationProcessor deps.lifecycle.compiler
    implementation deps.room.runtime
    annotationProcessor deps.room.compiler

    // Android Testing Support Library's runner and rules
    androidTestImplementation deps.atsl.runner
    androidTestImplementation deps.atsl.rules
    androidTestImplementation deps.room.testing
    androidTestImplementation deps.arch_core.testing

    // Espresso UI Testing
    androidTestImplementation deps.espresso.core
    androidTestImplementation deps.espresso.contrib
    androidTestImplementation deps.espresso.intents

    // Resolve conflicts between main and test APK:
    androidTestImplementation deps.support.annotations
    androidTestImplementation deps.support.v4
    androidTestImplementation deps.support.app_compat
    androidTestImplementation deps.support.design
}
```

I am not able to understand why they have written all the dependency starting with `deps.*`. Could anybody help me understand the code. Thanks in advance.
Here is the [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/app/build.gradle) to the repo.

Comment: they are declared 'deps' in 'versions.gradle' file in the root directory

Answer (score 13):

`deps` is an instance of `Map` class that is set on `project` instance and defined in [versions.gradle](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/versions.gradle#L5) file. This `versions.gradle` file is in turn [applied](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/build.gradle#L20) in root `build.gradle` script, hence `deps` can be used in subprojects.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Opal suggestions.

deps is a placeholder defined at the project level.You can find it in [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/versions.gradle#L5)

Say for Dagger2, the deps is defined as follows in the versions.gradle file which is one step above the module level .

```
*def dagger = [:]
dagger.runtime = "com.google.dagger:dagger:$versions.dagger"
dagger.android = "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$versions.dagger"
.....

deps.dagger = dagger*
```

[Image if code not well formatted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEVHa.png)

This way it helps in having the same version applied to all modules for the project .
And only the modules which need the particular dependency can declare it at their build.gradle definition.