# What is this implemention? Android

Tags: android, dependencies

I've downloaded a [repository](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/main/NavigationAdvancedSample) from github and in the dependencies I've founded this

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation deps.kotlin.stdlib
implementation deps.support.app_compat
implementation deps.support.design
implementation deps.support.core_ktx
implementation deps.constraint_layout
implementation deps.arch_core.runtime

// Navigation
implementation deps.navigation.runtime_ktx
implementation deps.navigation.fragment_ktx
implementation deps.navigation.ui_ktx

// Android Testing Support Library's runner and rules
androidTestImplementation deps.atsl.runner
androidTestImplementation deps.atsl.rules
androidTestImplementation deps.room.testing
androidTestImplementation deps.arch_core.testing

// Espresso UI Testing
androidTestImplementation deps.espresso.core
androidTestImplementation deps.espresso.contrib
androidTestImplementation deps.espresso.intents
```

}

So I've tried to instal those dependencies to my project but I got an error

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
```

> Could not get unknown property 'deps' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

So any ideas what this "desp" means?

Comment: I think you'll find your answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47236796/what-is-deps-in-implementation-deps-support-app-compat

Comment: @LionErez thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a way (with ExtraPropertiesExtension) to keep `build.gradle` files as clean as possible with an external file like a `version.gradle` file in which there are all dependencies and their version.

```
buildscript {
    apply from: 'versions.gradle'
    ...
}
```

You can find this `version.gradle` at the root of the project. This file is applied in the `./build.gradle`

The developer decided to manage his dependencies in this way but you can find many others.

This [article](https://medium.com/doubletapp/how-to-manage-gradle-dependencies-in-the-android-project-proper-way-dad51fd4fe7) present 3 ways to do it.